# Use Windows 10 virtual keyboard auto-completion api inside a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, windows-10, autosuggest

When using the windows 10 virtual keyboard, it offert a auto-completion feature like smartphone keyboard. I want to use this feature in a WPF application without having to open the virtual keyboard.

Does an API exist to get those suggestion from a C#/Wpf app?

There is spell check feature in WPF but it is different from auto-completion.

- Spell check can only suggest a word if it's completly typed but with a few mistake. It can't suggest word if you only type the begining of a word.
- It don't work with several word with missing space or apostrophe. For example, in french "cest" will be corrected to "c'est" and "helloworld" will be corrected to "hello world"

Comment: There is no such native feature in WPF. You would have to use a service like an Azure service or any other e.g. REST API. Autocomplete involves a sort of AI that usually detects typos and is able to analyze the context in order to suggest words without the user having  to type anything..

Comment: A very trivial solution would be to download a dictionary to create a fast lookup table (usually based  on a sorted tree structure like the SortedDictionary class or use a database or a REST service) and then fetch words that start with the current input. This won't provide the best user experience but is better than nothing and very simple to implement.

Comment: You can turn the feature on with hardware keyboard on win10. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/98269-turn-off-autocorrect-hardware-keyboard-windows-10-a.html